# Handling data between sibling compoenents and updating the parent: React hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

I am having this requirement of moving around data between two tables. I get data in the parent component, which then will be passed down to the `<Available/>` . From this component I should be able to select data items and add it( also Add  to the `<Selected/>` component. Once added, the row should be deleted inside Available and moved to Selected. In the similar way I should be able to delete( also Delete All) the data from the `<Selected/>` component, which in turn should be put back to the `<Avaiable/>`.
I am using react-table for the grid purposes

Code that I have tried : https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-example-forked-0rqb9

Can someone help me here

App Component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { data } from "./data";
import { Available } from "./Available";
import { Selected } from "./Selected";

function App() {
  const [dataConfig, setDataConfig] = useState({ available: [], selected: [] });

  useEffect(() => {
    setDataConfig({ ...dataConfig, available: data });
  });

  function updateDataConfig() {}

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <div>Available Table</div>
        <Available
          available={dataConfig.available}
          updateDataConfig={updateDataConfig}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <div> Selected Table</div>
        <Selected
          selected={dataConfig.selected}
          updateDataConfig={updateDataConfig}
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Available

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactTable from "react-table";
import "react-table/react-table.css";

export function Available({ available }) {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [columns, setColumns] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setData(available);
  }, [available.length]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const columns = [
      {
        id: "check",
        accessor: "checkbox",
        Cell: ({ original }) => {
          return <input type="checkbox" className="checkbox" />;
        }
      },
      {
        id: "name",
        accessor: "name",
        Header: "Header"
      },
      {
        id: "age",
        accessor: "age",
        Header: "Age"
      }
    ];
    setColumns(columns);
  }, []);

  function handleAdd() {}

  function handleAddAll() {}

  return (
    <>
      <button type="button" onClick={handleAddAll}>
        Add All
      </button>
      <button type="button" onClick={handleAdd}>
        Add Selected
      </button>

      <ReactTable
        data={data}
        columns={columns}
        showPagination={false}
        minRows={5}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

Selected

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactTable from "react-table";
import "react-table/react-table.css";

export function Selected({ selected }) {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [columns, setColumns] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setData(selected);
  }, [selected.length]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const columns = [
      {
        id: "check",
        accessor: "checkbox",
        Cell: ({ original }) => {
          return (
            <input type="button" onClick={handleDelete}>
              Delete
            </input>
          );
        }
      },
      {
        id: "name",
        accessor: "name",
        Header: "Header"
      },
      {
        id: "age",
        accessor: "age",
        Header: "Age"
      }
    ];
    setColumns(columns);
  }, []);

  function handleDeleteAll() {}

  function handleDelete() {}

  return (
    <>
      <button type="button" onClick={handleDeleteAll}>
        Delete All
      </button>
      <ReactTable
        data={data}
        columns={columns}
        showPagination={false}
        minRows={5}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check a small working version of my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-example-forked-behv4)

I have implemented the "Add" and "Delete" functionality.
For some reason, checkboxes stay checked and I cannot understand why, but you can get a clear idea of how it works.

Also i removed the inner state `data` and used only data passed by props.

Hope it helps you continue your work.

Comment: Tried Delete All, Add All, It seems like selected is not updated. Can you help me out here please? Thanks again.

Comment: yes I didnt implement these. I just showed you a point where to start by implementing some methods not all of them :) You need to try too in order to learn better :)

Comment: had some free time and in order for the answer to be accepted, i implemented the add all and delete all functionalities :)